# Built-in function Name error while joining two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
>   'Mem_date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

This is my first attempt at joining two tables and this may beg for a simple answer, but why am I getting this error?

```
select 
    e.Meme_lev2 as Group#, 
    e.MEME_GRPN as Groupname, 
    mem_date(MONTH),
    COUNT(*)
from 
    Impact.dbo.tbl_mem m
left join 
    Impact.dbo.tbl_meme e on e.MEME_ID1 = m.MEM_ID1
inner join 
    impactwork.dbo.tbl_mmonth x on x.mem_date between convert(varchar(10), e.meme_eff, 101) and convert(varchar(10), e.meme_trm, 101)
                                and x.mem_date between '01/01/2015' and '03/31/2015'
where
    e.MEME_LEV2 = '52024' 
    and GETDATE() between '01/16/2015' and '06/16/2015'
group by 
    mem_date(month)
```

Comment: `mem_date(MONTH)` there is no function mem_date.

Comment: I don't think `mem_date` is a built-in function in SQL Server.

Comment: Move the WHERE clause's e.MEME_LEV2 = '52024' condition to LEFT JOIN's ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Now it executes as an inner join...)

Comment: mem_date is a column name in tbl_mmonth

Comment: But when you write mem_date(MONTH) it looks like a function...

Comment: Should it be `MONTH(mem_date)`?

Comment: If you are trying to group by the month, you need to reverse your order then: MONTH(mem_date).  You might want to add YEAR(mem_date) to avoid grouping the same month, unless that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @jarlh Then I receive errors for the inner join.

Comment: @AnalystSupreme then post those errors

Comment: Why are you converting your `date` fields to `varchar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `(MONTH)` after Mem_Date makes SQL Server think it's a function that you are trying to pass a parameter to.  Correct it to:

```
select 
    e.Meme_lev2 as Group#, 
    e.MEME_GRPN as Groupname, 
    MONTH(x.mem_date) AS mem_date, -- changed
    COUNT(*)
from Impact.dbo.tbl_mem m
left join Impact.dbo.tbl_meme e 
    on e.MEME_ID1 = m.MEM_ID1
inner join impactwork.dbo.tbl_mmonth x 
    on x.mem_date between convert(varchar(10), e.meme_eff, 101) and convert(varchar(10), e.meme_trm, 101)
    and x.mem_date between '01/01/2015' and '03/31/2015'
where
    e.MEME_LEV2 = '52024' 
    and GETDATE() between '01/16/2015' and '06/16/2015'
group by 
    e.Meme_lev2, 
    e.MEME_GRPN, 
    MONTH(x.mem_date)
```

Please note that I also added the additional fields in your `SELECT` statement to the `GROUP BY` clause.

EDIT: so you can see what @jarlh is suggesting:

```
select 
    e.Meme_lev2 as Group#, 
    e.MEME_GRPN as Groupname, 
    MONTH(x.mem_date) AS mem_date, -- changed
    COUNT(*)
from 
    Impact.dbo.tbl_mem m
     left join 
    Impact.dbo.tbl_meme e on 
        e.MEME_ID1 = m.MEM_ID1 AND 
        e.MEME_LEV2 = '52024' 
     inner join impactwork.dbo.tbl_mmonth x on 
            x.mem_date between convert(varchar(10), e.meme_eff, 101) and convert(varchar(10), e.meme_trm, 101) and 
            x.mem_date between '01/01/2015' and '03/31/2015'
--where
--  GETDATE() between '01/16/2015' and '06/16/2015'
group by 
    e.Meme_lev2, 
    e.MEME_GRPN, 
    MONTH(x.mem_date)
```

Comment: That seems to have solved that issue. Only problem now is that it says mem_date is an ambiguous column name. This column exists in dbo.tbl_mmonth which is referenced above. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just like you already did in your `BETWEEN` statement, you can include the table alias in the `MONTH()` function.  See the edited code above (assuming you want `x.mem_date`)

Comment: Move the WHERE clause's e.MEME_LEV2 = '52024' condition to LEFT JOIN's ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Now it executes as an inner join...) And what's the purpose of GETDATE() between '01/16/2015' and '06/16/2015'?

Comment: @jarlh I move that clause and I receive 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner''

Comment: AnalystSupreme, see the edit for what I believe @jarlh is trying to show you (jarlh, feel free to edit it if you desire).

Comment: Ah, I see. That does help. That successfully pulls everything, however that leaves me with a column without a column name and two separate tables, each having a different value for mem_date

Comment: Analyst, if you need a column name for that last one, then add it - it's your query, not mine!  I have no idea what you mean by "Two separate tables" - again, this is your data and your query.  I can point out the syntax errors, such as the one that caused your initial problem, but I really have no idea whether the query that you built is going to do what you need it to.  That part is up to you.

Comment: @AHigginsWhen I run this query, it has two separate tables. It seems as if the join never truly worked. The first table contains mem_date and the second tables contains all the other fields.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense - do you have more than one `SELECT` statement in the script you are running? If all you are executing is the code block below "EDIT: so you can see what @jarlh is suggesting" then you should only see one result set returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want `MONTH(mem_date)` instead of `mem_date(MONTH)`.

`MONTH` is a function, `mem_date` is not.